# Laravel 5 redirect to previous root after filters

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-5, response, middleware

I ran into simple problem but I still can't solve it. At the moment i got middleware which checks user status, if it's 0 middleware redirects user to choose status root. So how do i redirect user to route, after successfully picking status, where he got cought by middleware?

My status check middleware:

```
if (Auth::user()->status == '0') {
    return new RedirectResponse(url('/user/user-status'));
}
return $next($request);
```

I'm using laravel 5.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried dd'ing the redirectresponse? Normal behavior would be to do a `return Redirect::to('/user/user-status');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets look into the option of using `Redirect::intended()` and `Redirect::guest()`

The code behind `Redirect::intended()` is:

```
public function intended($default, $status = 302, $headers = array(), $secure = null)
{
        $path = $this->session->get('url.intended', $default);

        $this->session->forget('url.intended');

        return $this->to($path, $status, $headers, $secure);
}
```

The one for `Redirect::guest()` is :

```
public function guest($path, $status = 302, $headers = array(), $secure = null)
{
    $this->session->put('url.intended', $this->generator->full());

    return $this->to($path, $status, $headers, $secure);
}
```

So basically, this means you can do this:

```
if (!Auth::user()->status) {
    return redirect()->guest('/user/user-status');
}
return $next($request);
```

Then once the process of setting status is completed, you simply run:

`return redirect()->intended()`;

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the redirect provider. Into this function, Laravel memories the intended path.

```
           if (Auth::user()->status == '0') {
            {
                \Session::flash('flash_message','Please choose a status.');
                return redirect()->guest('/user/user-status');
            }


            return $next($request);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if (Auth::user()->status == '0') {
    return redirect()->guest('/user/user-status');
}
return $next($request);
```

According to code documentation, `redirect()->guest()` does this: "Create a new redirect response, while putting the current URL in the session.". Then, in your "user status" page, you can get your intended URL in session with `Session::get('url.intended')` or `return redirect()->intended('default-route-if-not-set');`